# I can't edit my mail text in the PHP mailer

Tags: php, html, text, phpmailer, edit

I have set up a site and added a contact form into it. `Php mailer` work correctly but when the mail text arrives to me there is no empty between the letters. All of them is adjoining. I want to list titles one under to other mailer.php. The code is like this

```php
 require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); 
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SetLanguage("tr", "phpmailer/language");
    $mail->CharSet  ="utf-8";

    $mail->Username = "sample"; 
    $mail->Password = "sample"; 
    $mail->SetFrom("sample@sample.com", "Baslik"); 
    $mail->AddAddress("sample@sample.com"); 

    $mail->Subject = "Web Sitesi İletişim Mesajı";



    include("iletisim.html");


    $mail->Body = $frmName= $_POST["frmName"].
                  $frmCity= $_POST["frmCity"] .
                  $adressatiri= $_POST["adressatiri"]. 
                  $adressatiri2= $_POST["adressatiri2"].
                  $email= $_POST["email"] .
                  $frmTelephone= $_POST["frmTelephone"] .
                  $frmPhoneType= $_POST["frmPhoneType"] .
                  $frmContactBy= $_POST["frmContactBy"] .
                  $frmBestTime= $_POST["frmBestTime"]  .
                  $frmMessage= $_POST["frmMessage"];
                  
   
     if(!$mail->Send()){
                    echo "Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
                    echo "Mesajınız Gonderilmistir";
    }

    ?>
```

and `contact.html` file is like this. If you can help me i will be very appreciate. Because i didnt solve this problem.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta name="description"  content="Karadeniz Teknik Üniversitesi Elektrik Elektronik Mühendisliği Mezunu Sena DOĞAN'ın Kişisel Web Sitesidir." />
<meta name="keywords" content="sena doğan, web sitesi, kişisel web sitesi, web sitesi örnekleri, tasarım, elektrik, elektronik, elektrik elektronik mühendisliği, elektikli araba, ktü, karadeniz teknik üniversitesi, kalibrasyon, dokunmatik ekran, hakkımda, eğitim, proje, galeri, iletişim "/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.senadogan.com/iletisim.html" hreflang="tr" />
<title>Sena DOĞAN Kişisel Web Sitesi | İletişim</title>
<style type="text/css">

  body,p, table, th, td, div {
    
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
 
}


th {
  background-color:#0080C0;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:18px;
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
}
input.text, textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 99%;
}
.text:focus, textarea:focus {
  background-color: #FFFACC;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#mydiv {
  margin-left: 0px ;
  margin-right: auto;
   width: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  
  
  
}
td.colone {
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:6px;
  width:20%;
}
td.coltwo {
  color:red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top:9px;
}
td.colthree {
  width:80%
}
table.border {
  border: 1px solid #0080C0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
    
</style>
<link href="banner.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url(images/elektronik-arkaplan.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container"> 
      <div id="mydiv" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;">
      <form method="POST" action="mailer.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" value="samplecontactus.html" name="referer">
<table class="border" width="510" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3" align="center">İletişim İçin Lütfen Aşağıdaki Kutuları Doldurun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Ad Soyad</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="frmName" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Şehir</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="frmCity" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Adres</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="adressatiri" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Adres-2</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text"  name="adressatiri2" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="colone">E-posta</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input class="text" type="text" name="email" style="width:98%;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Telefon</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="200"><input class="text" type="text" name="frmTelephone" style="width:200px;"></td>
          <td>
            <select size="1" name="frmPhoneType">
            <option value="Ev">Ev</option>
            <option value="Is">İş</option>
            <option value="Cep">Cep</option>
            
            
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Görüşme Şekli</td>
    <td class="coltwo">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="1">
            <select size="1" name="frmContactBy">
            <option value="Telefon">Telefon</option>
            <option value="Email">E-Posta</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select size="1" name="frmBestTime">
            <option value="Sabah">Gündüz</option>
            <option value="Ogle">Öğle</option>
            <option value="Aksam">Akşam</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone">Mesaj</td>
    <td class="coltwo">*</td>
    <td class="colthree"><textarea class="text" name="frmMessage" style="width:98%;height:100px;"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="colone" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="colthree"><input type="submit" value="Gönder" name="submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><div style="height:5px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
<span style="color:red;">*</span> = Doldurulması zorunlu alan<br />
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `$mail->Body` is concatenating all form values using `.` . You can amend it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of my researches I have found a solution like this. Now works for me .

```html
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>İsim:</span> ".$_POST["frmName"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Şehir:</span> ".$_POST["frmCity"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Adres 1:</span> ".$_POST["adressatiri"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Adres 2:</span> ".$_POST["adressatiri2"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>E-posta:</span> ".$_POST["email"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Telefon:</span> ".$_POST["frmTelephone"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Telefon Tipi:</span> ".$_POST["frmPhoneType"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Görüşme Şekli:</span> ".$_POST["frmContactBy"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>En uygun zaman:</span> ".$_POST["frmBestTime"]."</a><br>
    <a><span style='font-weight: bold;'>Mesaj:</span> ".$_POST["frmMessage"]."</a>
```

Now I am taking mails like this below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because HTML collapses white space. The easiest way to fix this is to convert real line breaks into HTML break tags in your message body:

```
$mail->Body = nl2br($mail->Body);
```